# PostgreSQL: Creating a new view by filtering rows based on column values in numerous rows

Tags: postgresql, magento

I am working with a magento table like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| date product_name product_id product_type time order_id qty_ordered last_order  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2017/2/15 X 18W1 custom 1900 12 1 2016/12/10                                    |
| 2017/2/15 X 18W1 simple 1900 12 1 2016/12/3                                     |
| 2017/2/15 XX 18W2 simple 1900 12 3 2016/12/4                                    |
| 2017/2/20 Y 22Y34 simple 1532 19 1 2017/1/9                                     |
| 2017/2/20 Z 22Y35 simple 1532 19 2 2017/1/15                                    |
| 2017/2/20 Z 22Y35 custom 1532 19 2 2016/9/12                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to make a new view, by first looking for rows which have the same order_id and product_id. Then out of the two rows, I want to only take the row where product_type = "custom". I want to also only take certain columns.

So my final table after doing this operation from aboveshould look like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| date      | product_name | product_id | product_type | order_id | qty_ordered |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/15 |            X |       18W1 |       custom | 12       | 1           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/15 | XX           | 18W2       | simple       | 12       | 3           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/20 | Y            | 22Y34      | simple       | 19       | 1           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/20 | Z            | 22Y35      | custom       | 19       | 2           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

So far, I've tried using the following query to no avail:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table GROUP BY order_id, product_id HAVING "count"(*)>1;) THEN 
SELECT table.date, table.product_name, table.product_id, table.product_type, table.order_id, table.qty_ordered
WHERE product_type = "configurable" FROM table;
ELSE SELECT SELECT table.date, table.product_name, table.product_id, table.product_type, table.order_id, table.qty_ordered FROM table;
END IF;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by selecting all the custom entries, and then selecting those simple entries where there is not a corresponding custom entry.  Something like:

```
create view v_tab
as
select * from tab where product_type = 'custom'
union all
select * from tab t1 where product_type = 'simple' and
  not exists 
    (select * from tab t2 
     where t2.order_id = t1.order_id 
     and t2.product_id = t1.product_id 
     and t2.product_type = 'custom')
```